# Hide a td after creating a new row in datatable using jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

Onload I'm hiding one column both in thead and tbody and it works fine. 
When I Dynamically add a new row and update the table, the new row displays the hidden column.

Here is how I insert the new row:

```
thedatatable.row.add(row).node();
thedatatable.draw();
```

How can I hide the column of the newly updated row?

Comment: Where is your hide column code? You need to call hide function again after you redraw the table.

Comment: show us how you managed to hide the columns.

Comment: @abpatil.. that's what I don't know how to hide after redraw.  Can u plz let me know how to hide

Comment: Show your full code. How u r hiding it in Onload?

Comment: @ScanQR I have hide the columns using display:none

Comment: @Syed it wont work then for dynamically addd rows. Try following answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `hide` the `column` of `DataTable` using provided `API`s and in this case it is `.visible()`

If you `hide` it in following manner,

```
    column.visible( false );
```

Then any dynamically added `row` won't show those `columns`.

Comment: But which column it will hide and where to write this line